# How can I solve the problem of class in Laravel's Mpdf?

Tags: php, laravel, mpdf

I followed a tutorial, and in the tutorial, he is not using any namespace. I tried to solve this but failed. Can somebody provide me with a solution?

Laravel Mpdf is creating a class issue. The error is.

> Class "Mpdf\Fonts\Config\ConfigVariables" not found

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PdfTestController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// Route::get('/pdfTest', [PdfTestController::class, 'index']);

Route::get('/pdfTest', function(){
    $defaultConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
    $fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];

    $defaultFontConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
    $fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontData'];

    $path = public_path() . "/fonts";
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
        'format' => 'A4',
        'orientation' => 'P',
        'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [$path]),
        'fontData' => $fontData + [
            'solaimanlipi' => [
                'R' => 'SolaimanLipi.ttf',
                'useOTL' => 0xFF,
            ],
        ],
        'default_font' => 'solaimanlipi'
    ]);

    $mpdf->WriteHTML(view('card-download-test'));
    $mpdf->Output('card.pdf', 'I');
});
```

Comment: You provide no context about this file, how is it being called, why do you expect classes to be loaded? The code provided doesn't even contain the class name in the error message.

Comment: Do you use same versions of mpdf? can you see the file (ConfigVariables) in your vendor directory?

Comment: Which version of mPDF you use?